# Angular routing (AuthGuard) inside a Docker Container

Tags: angular, docker, angular-routing, angular-router-guards, auth-guard

I have just deployed my Angular project inside a Docker Container. Path for me to access to the site is: localhost:4200, because on my machine is listening on 4200, but inside the container is listening at port 80.
I'm using Angular routing, here's the file:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'Login', component: LandingPageComponent},
  { path: '', component: AppComponent},
  { path: 'Home', component: BlogHomeComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard],
  children:[
    { path: '', component: BlogHomeComponent},
    { path: "Posts", component: PostsComponent},
    { path: 'NewPost', component: CreatePostComponent},
    { path: 'Post/:id', component: SinglePostComponent}
]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is, instead, my AuthGuard:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard  {



constructor(private authService: AuthService, private route: Router){}

  canActivate():boolean {
    if(this.authService.isLoggedIn() == true){
      return true;
    } else {
      this.route.navigateByUrl("");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

It should check everytime I try to access routes if I'm logged. And it works fine when I run the app from consolde (without docker). Everytime I try to access a path, it checks if I'm logged, and when I'm not it throws me directly to the Login page. But this is not working when I deployed the app inside the docker container. When I go to a page I'm not allowed to, I get this error in the browser:
[image]
Why that? If I go to the exact same link (localhost:4200/Home/Posts) when I'm running it from angular cli (with ng server), it actually push me back to the login if I'm not logged into.

---

EDIT

---

Here is the Dockerfile of the Angular project:

```
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/front-end-blog-demo /usr/share/nginx/html
```

And here's the Docker-compose file, because I'm running with docker-compose both backend and frontend:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./FrontEnd-BlogDemo
    ports:
      - 4200:80
  backend:
    build: ./BackEnd-BlogDemo
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup your webserver correctly. If a page was not found, then the webserver should return the `index.html`. It should never throws a `404`.

You provide no information about your Docker-Image, so I only can refer you to this page https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

---

### Edit

Yes, nginx is your webserver. You need a config-file so that nginx never returns a `404`.
Here is one of mine projects with a nginx on-board. I marked the important row for you.
https://github.com/AndreKoepke/home-system/blob/master/frontend/nginx/conf.d/default.conf#L39

You can also have look on my [dockerfile](https://github.com/AndreKoepke/home-system/blob/master/frontend/Dockerfile), to see how to put the config to nginx.

And at the end a little hint: You used `npm install`in your dockerfile. You should use `npm ci` instead.

Comment: I edited the post with dockerfile and docker-compose, meanwhile I'll go read the documentation!

Comment: I updated my answer to your edit. :)